# How to modify a list within function, from another function

Tags: python, list, function, global-variables

I have this following code:

```
x = []
def func1():
    global x
    x = [1,2,3]
    print x


def func2():
    global x
    x.append(4)


func1()
```

I am trying to append to the list in func1, from func2, and display these changes within the first function. Is this possible?

Comment: it is possible, but you need to _call_ `func2` at some point. And functions can take parameters you know?

Comment: okay I'll give that a go, thanks!

Comment: [Are you sure, you want to learn Python2 instead of Python3?](https://pythonclock.org/)

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly possible (and your code is basically correct, aside from the fact you're not calling `func2` anywhere), but it is not generally advisable.

For a full explanation of why global state (which is what `x` is, in your example) is normally a bad idea, see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil for example. Also, countless articles you can find online.

But, briefly, you ideally want you programs to be as predictable as possible. When your code, inevitably, doesn't do what you think it should, you want it to be very easy to track down your mistake. Global state makes this **very hard**. This is essentially because some random part of your code base *could* just change `x` from under you in a way that's not very easy to track down.

What should you do instead? In this case, probably just pass the list `x` into each function that wants to use it. Then it's very easy to see at a glance where `x` might change, because you've had to pass it in to any functions that might change it. You can much more easily track how data changes through the flow of your program.